# Сервер удаленных рабочих столов в Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-server-2012

На работе установили новый сервер под управлением Windows Server 2012, настроил сервер удаленных рабочих столов.
Сервер работает в рабочей группе, периодически пользователи не могут подключиться к серверу, плюс к этому почему-то обрывается ссесия.
Я проверил: сетка в порядке, пользователям доступ разрешен.

В логах написано: Ошибка 1306. Клиенту посредника подключений к удаленному рабочему столу не удалось перенаправить пользователя. Ошибка:NULL.

Просьба помочь в решении данного вопроса.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: возможно вам быстрее помогут на [http://serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Раз периодически, то скорее всего, упираетесь в ограничения в политиках или лицензии на количество сеансов.

Comment: Лицензии не может быть, потому что пользователей входит пока только двое, лицензий больше.